# how can i handle if my leaflet web application has heavy traffic

Tags: leaflet

now I use leaflet.

I want to know what are their policies about heavy traffic.

like OSM, I have to make another server? then, how can i do?

thanks for answering.

Comment: this question isnt very clear, edit your question to ask one specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet is a javascript library and does not provide tiles. So there is no limit in using leaflet.

Your question is more towards the provider of the tiles that leaflet uses.

For example:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

The map you see is actually a set of images (usually 256x256 pixels). There are served by a tiles server. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames.

The limitation you want to know is the limitation of the tiles server.

Leaflet is the glue that knows which tiles to show according to the lat,lng you want to show.
The TileLayer you create tells leaflet where it must get the tiles from.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Just i didn't understand leaflet, openstreetmap.
if i use leaflet, where is the map comming? is that openstreetmap? how can i handle that?

Comment: thanks for your comment.
can i ask you something more?
when i use map with angular2, which is better? google map? leaflet??
I pray for your nice day